# Unique Solutions of a Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am a newbie to differential equations, and not sure how to approach this question:

Determine a region of the xy plane for which the following differential equation: $(y-x)\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}=y+x$ would have a unique solution whose graph passes through a point
$(x_{0},y_{0})$
in the region.

I thought maybe to start by plotting it with Mathematica or Matlab but not sure how to plot it in order to see the region. Can you kindly assist with the solution of this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem)?

Comment: No, unfortunately I am not.

Comment: Your instructor may not have called it that.  It's sometimes called the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. the substitution $u=y-x$ leads to the equation $uu'=2x$.
2. $(u^2)'=2uu'$.

Comment: Damned ! Why the downvote ??

Answer (score 0):

Hint: write the equation in the form $$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \ldots $$
Where is the right side not a nice function of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Hi Robert. It's not a nice function when x=y, division by 0.

Comment: Correct.  So your region must exclude that.  You also want the region to be connected.  So...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

The unique solutions are such that the slope is uniquely determined at every point.

This is obviously not the case where $x=y$.